# Install ubuntu into virtual machine

Tags: installation

All, I download ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso try to install it in the VMWare. During the installation , Everything looks fine. But when it install the vmware tools . It seems it didn't fail with it .But Why I can't see the Graphic UI ? Any one know what happen to it ? thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do a good research before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login inside and type any of these commands below to get into Graphical mode.

```
startx
gdm
lightdm
```

Hope it works!